# Gollum Wiki editing fails because of a permission issue

Tags: permissions, ruby, wiki

I have been using the gollum wiki and it has worked fine so far. After mainly updating conda (which should have nothing to do with gollum), I get the following error message when I try to save edits to a wiki page

```
Errno::EACCES - Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - /home/pfeiffer/Projects/wikis/phd.wiki/.git/objects/db/cc3...
```

Googling has not yielded any success yet, just some indication that it might be a ruby problem. I tried reinstalling the ruby packages via apt, but this did not help.

My approach so far has been to uninstall gollum and reinstall, but this also failed. Although this is some time ago, I am pretty sure I installed gollum via gem., that is

```
apt install ruby ruby-dev build-essential zlib1g-dev libicu-dev
gem install gollum
```

But after I uninstall it via

```
 gem uninstall -aIx gollum
```

which gives no output, I can still execute `gollum`on the command line.

So if I cannot repair the ruby issue, how to properly uninstall gollum?